# Where do I specify ajc compiler options when using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I would like to troubleshoot my aspects. http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/pdguide/messages.html suggests to start by passing certain flags (like -verbose or -XLint or -showWeaveInfo) to the compiler.

How do I specify these in Eclipse?
Thanks.

Comment: You add most VM arguments in the "Run Configurations..." menu choice but compiler options may not be specified there.  Hrmm

Comment: These may be options that you can only use with Ant or Maven from the command line.  Can you even see the compiler output in Eclipse?  Can you add more information to the question about what debugging information you need from these compiler flags?

Comment: These are excellent questions, but I am not the one to answer, rather to ask. Even if I can see the compiler output I just do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> AspectJ Compiler -> Other to set this globally.  You can also have per-project settings.  Project -> Properties -> AspectJ Compiler -> Other.

There are lots of options there, you just need to play around with things until you get this right.

To see the compiler output, go to Window -> Show view -> AJDT Event trace.  I'm not sure if the proper filters are selected by default, so if you don't see what you want to see, click on the filters icon and click "Select All".